# GMS2 returns instance_create_layer :: specified layer "text_layer" does not exist even though the layer exists how do i fix this?

Tags: game-maker, gml, game-maker-studio-2

heres the code

```
var _obj;

if (instance_exists(obj_text)) _obj = obj_txt_queued; else _obj = obj_text;
with (instance_create_layer(0, 0, "text_layer", _obj))
{
    msg = argument[0];
    if (instance_exists(other)) originInstance = other.id else originInstance = noone;
    if (argument_count > 1) background = argument[1]; else background = 1;
    
}

with (obj_phae)
{ if (state != scr_player_state_lock)
    { 
        lastState = state;
        state = scr_player_state_lock;
    }
}
```

[layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9u9tD.png)

I tried removing any extra rooms that were not needed and I tried changing the layer name to something else.

I also tried using var instance_create_layer() but that obviously didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused at this part:

```
with (instance_create_layer(0, 0, "text_layer", _obj))
```

Especially the `with()`, as that function will go through every object in the room if it sees an object within the parameter, since you suggested to create a new object with it, I'm surprised it doesn't create an infinite loop. Maybe it works, I've never tried it myself, but I think there's a more logical way to assign variables from one object to a newly created object.

Assuming you want to use the `With()` statement to address the variables within the `_obj`, I think you can manage something similair through this function:

```
var object = instance_create_layer(0, 0, "text_layer", _obj)
object.msg = argument[0];
object.originInstance = id
if (argument_count > 1) object.background = argument[1]; else object.background = 1;
```

It's probably a given at this point, but double-check that this part of code can only run if it's in the same room that has a layer called "text_layer"

In the worst case, you may also try out `instance_create_depth()` and use the build-in depth variable from the object instead of the layer names. Using depth is more flexible, but less organised than layers.

Comment: "Especially the with(), as that function will go through every object in the room if it sees an object within the parameter" - not at all, with can be used to execute code in scope of a single object (or struct), and the author's use case is demonstrated [in the manual](https://manual.yoyogames.com/#t=GameMaker_Language%2FGML_Overview%2FLanguage_Features%2Fwith.htm).

Comment: I see, I've only used it with just the object as parameter, so I wasn't aware it could be used for much more purposes. So that's interesting!